# Condition for an algebra to be finite, which does not use the underlying set

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra

> I wonder whether there is any categorical property that picks out
>   exactly the finite algebras of some algebraic theory *without*
>   referring to the underlying set.

What I mean is: I don't want to use the the structure of a functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set}$ from my algebraic category. This is (obviously) not so interesting, but more importantly I want the property to make sense in the *absence* of any such structure too (obviously I could have a different interpretation then, I'm open to anything interesting).

No cheating allowed, of course! You can't refer to the free object on a singleton, because that doesn't make any sense in a general category (e.g. you can't use $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb Z, G)$ to count the elements in a group $G$ as $\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by some property involving the functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set}$; even though you can characterise $\mathbb{Z}$ by different means, this probably doesn't make much sense for other kinds of algebras besides groups).

Here are some necessary conditions for an algebra $A$ to be finite (but I don't see how any of them are sufficient):

- the poset of subobjects $\operatorname{Sub} A$ is finite
- $A$ is finitely generated ($\mathcal{A}(X,\_)$ preserves filtered colimits of monos)
- the monoid of endomorphisms $\operatorname{End} A$ is finite
- $A$ is Dedekind-finite, i.e.: every mono (injection) $A\to A$ is an isomorphism

I'd also be interested in a property for some (not *to small*) subclass of all theories or a statement, that what I'm trying to do is infeasible.

Comment: $\mathcal{A}(X,-)$ is a functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Set}$. Did you mean to exclude only the usage of the forgetful functor?

Comment: Yes. But again you can't / shouldn't just take $X$ to be the free object on a singleton, because that's then the same as the forgetful functor (the notion of a free object doesn't make any sense in the absence of the forgetful functor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alluded to in the question, it is possible to characterize the finitely generated algebras $F$ (e.g., as those for which $\mathcal{A}(F,-)$ preserves filtered colimits of monomorphisms).

If $F$ is finitely generated, then a homomorphism $F\to A$ is determined by the images of a finite set of generators, so if $A$ is finite then $\mathcal{A}(F,A)$ is finite.

Conversely, if $F$ is the free algebra on one generator, then $\mathcal{A}(F,A)$ has the same cardinality as $A$.

So the finite algebras $A$ are characterized as those for which $\mathcal{A}(F,A)$ is finite for every finitely generated algebra $F$.

Comment: Oh, that sounds amazing! Now I only need to convince myself that it is true.

Comment: @StefanPerko: A map from a finitely generated algebra is determined by the images of the generators. And the free object on one generator is a finitely generated algebra.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you, it is clear to me now.

Comment: Nice; could you expand on the “finitely generated”? Otherwise it looks a little circular (perhaps it's just me).

Comment: Why is that so? Let $\mathcal A$ be the category of $k$-algebra for an infinite field $k$. Then for $F=k[x]$ and $A=k$ I don't think $\mathcal A(F,A)$ is finite.

Comment: $k$ isn't finite.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf I've added some more explanation.

Comment: @CensiLI If $k$ is an infinite field then there is only one finite $k$-algebra (really, only one finite $k$-vector space). It's not an interesting situation for this question.

Comment: So finite algebra here means finite as a set but not finite as a vector space?

Comment: @CensiLI This question is about algebras in the sense of universal algebra or algebras as in: models of a Lawvere theory, e.g. groups, rings, monoids, lattices, $R$-modules, etc.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf See the question: $A$ is finitely generated iff $\mathcal{A}(A,\_)$ preserves filtered colimits of monos

Comment: @StefanPerko Get it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @StefanPerko Thank you both.